# Android calendar app with an easy option to reschedule tasks to the following day

Tags: android, calendar

I've tried a few Android calendar apps but I have found none that offered what I'm looking for: an easy way to reschedule undone tasks to the following day. Ideally, that should be done with a simple click.

Comment: Are we talking about calendars, or todo apps here? I'm using a calendar app where events can be moved by simple drag-and-drop. Not sure about todo apps, as I'm not using those very often.

Comment: I'm looking for calendar apps. Please post as an answer the name of the app you're using.

Comment: OK then, done – hope it fits your needs! As written, I can really recommend this app (me using it explicitly should prove it). I decided buying the pro to support a good development team (good support as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using **[Business Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal)** (actually the [paid "Pro" version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mikado.bizcalpro)) as my favorite calendar app – which I can recommend for many reasons. But sticking to your requirements here, the outstanding feature is to copy/move events via simple drag-and-drop:

[image: Business Calendar]
<sup>*Business Calendar* drag-and-drop (click to enlarge)</sup>

As the screenshot shows: in the calendar view (no matter whether daily/weekly/whatever), tap the "hand symbol" marked ① in the screenshot, then move your item by holding it and moving it. When you release it, that leads to ② to select the action. Make your choice, done.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but it looks like only the paid version has this feature.

Comment: I can't tell, as I'm no longer using the "free" version. OTOH, being free was not on your requirements list :)

Answer (score -1):

Try Calengoo.  Great app.  I have been using it for two years. Links to Google Tasks. But you modify the task within Calengoo.  A simple click on the Tasks then on the task you want to amend and then click on the due date and change it to next day on the calendar.  Really quick to do, unless of course you have a hundred!

Comment: I think that having to change a date does not satisfy the OPs criterion *Ideally, that should be done with a simple click*. Editing a task and changing the due date can be done in any task manager program.

Comment: Indeed, even with the Calendar shipped by default in Android.